# How to import output data from opl ilog in Excel (automatically)

Tags: excel, opl, ilog

I have solved a model with a software opl ilog simplex engine. Now I want my answers to be import in Excel. How can I do this?
Thank you for your help

Comment: You have to provide more information about how exactly you solved it. From OPL? From the command line? From a programming API?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are doing this from OPL, the manual has a [chapter that explains input and output via spreadsheets](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/opllangref/topics/opl_langref_spreadsheet.html).

Comment: Thank
I do not understand exactly how the output data can be automatically dumped by the software in Excel?

Comment: You have to be more specific about what you don't understand. Did you look at the examples in the chapter? Did you try to follow and run the example? The data is written using the `SheetWrite` statement.